# SQL time and date formatting against dual table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, dual-table

I am trying to only display the date and time of a table in a certain format. This format is DD-MON-YYYY and the time HH24:MI:SS. I don't understand how to make both formats work together. I can get them to function separately.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY', systimestamp,'HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

My error is 'too many arguments'. I want to understand why it isn't working.

Comment: Note that a `DATE` in Oracle, such as `SYSDATE`, is really a DATETIME (accurate to nearest second).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) TO_CHAR takes three arguments when using dates

- a date or date time
- a format model
- optional NLS parameter for the localization
  You can concatenate the two results together with this.

  select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')||' '|| TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

But why would when you do it one call

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

NB SQL is not case sensitive in regards to keywords.  Upper or lower case both work.

Comment: I understand now. Is there a reason you made to_char lowercase the first time and upper the second time?

Comment: So the concatenation acts the same even when only using one call. I didn't know that and it makes sense.

Comment: Injblue - it's not really a concatenation.  Both DATE and the various TIMESTAMP data types include both date and time as a fundamental part of the data.  DATE resolves time down to the second, and TIMSTAMP resolves down to the nano-second.  And of course, if you're still missing it, SYSDATE is a DATE and SYSTIMESTAMP is a TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```